# There is any font which have same from centerline

Tags: fonts, typography, typefaces

I'm Prasann.
I'm Graphic Designer ("Fresher").[image]

I'm Designing my portfolio right Now.
I'm creating Box to Put All Things(Brochure, Business card, etc.) into. in Box Design i need to Split the Fonts from Center. So 'Y' and 'R' MY WORK are not split from center.

So I would like know there is any font which have same from centerline. I have point out my problem in photo.
[image]
I would be grateful if if you answer this.
Thanks.

---

[image]

Thanks for answer.
This is the how box look like.
So one flap don't have to be longer than other it is locked by side strips.

Comment: I converted the "Answer" you left to an [Edit] - please use the [Edit] button in the future to add additional information to your Question. Only Answers should be left below. Thanks and welcome to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're designing a box and this word will be split by a flap, you might not need to find a font that can be split perfectly in the center.

**The reason is that you shouldn't create flaps on a fancy box (or even some brochures) that don't overlap each others;** one of the flap needs to be slightly longer than the other to make sure it closes properly. Usually, the only time you could create flaps that are perfectly equals is when there something else to hold them together (eg. tape, cord, ribbon, etc.) or on very cheap projects.

The panel/flap that will be longer than the other can be only 1/16" (1.5mm) longer.

With the font you have on this screenshot, you could make the top part overlaps the bottom part; it should be a bit longer. Therefore your top flap can be trimmed where you've put your circles on your screenshot. On the bottom part of your design, you'll make sure the part that will be hidden by the top part is visible. In other words, that's like a bleed for packaging.

When you'll close the flaps, you'll see it fits perfectly if you aligned you font well.

If you want to stick to your idea of finding the perfect font and doing your flaps perfectly equal for some reason, then I don't know which font could fit for this. You could always modify one with Illustrator. Maybe you could try your concept with a font a bit more straight like a Futura or Avant-Garde kind of font.

---

If you make a box or any kind of fancy thing for your portfolio, I strongly suggest you to make it right and do it the same way a professional printer would do it, especially if you plan to use it to get hired by a studio who does print projects. They will know you know nothing about packaging if you mess up your box; if you're not sure if the box will be perfect than find another idea that will! Personally, I recommend to keep things simple and create a portfolio where your sheets will not be folded or bent, and stick to the classical book-like kind of portfolio.